# Echo, grep and set variable issues

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the following scenario

Step1

```
 local output=$(sshpass -p ${PSSWD} ssh -tt -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$IP "$(< vXU-script.sh)")
```

step 2

```
mapfile -t RIU_ARRAY < <(echo "$output" | grep "RIU-[1-4] ----> ")
```

the above line will grep the following line

***RIU-1 ----> AB019030015 ----> 223a:c03a:261:1141:0:50:c389:22ff***

step 3 (loop RIU_ARRAY)

```
ip=$(echo "${item}" | awk -F" " '{print $5}')
```

**The above line will get the IP part 223a:c03a:261:1141:0:50:c389:22ff**

```
      if [ "${ip}" == "223a:c03a:261:1141:0:50:c389:22ff" ]; then
          echo "#### Same"
      else
        echo "#### Different"
      fi
```

The above line is always False and the following line is printed
**#### Different**

I expect it to be the same.
Is this because of the semi-colon or CLI console greped character encoding issues?

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: Where do you declare $item?

Comment: Consider running with '-x'. Most likely, there is hidden/"funny" character somewhere.

Comment: Replace `#### Different` with `echo "${ip}" | xxd` and see what the difference is.

Comment: consider syntaxe like: `ssh user@target /bin/sh <<eof` then command script ended by `eof`... And **Don't use `-t` switch** when piping output of `ssh`!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the 'sshpass | ssh -tt' will result in line ending with '\r\n'.

Considering 2 options - Filtering with 'tr' will (almost) always work. But the '-tt' seems cleaner.

1. The '-tt' cause terminal allocation, which is injecting '\r'. If possible, try running without it.
2. If this is not an option, pipe output into "tr -d '\r'"

```
 local output=$(sshpass -p ${PSSWD} ssh -tt -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$IP "$(< vXU-script.sh)" | tr -d '\r')
```